# Initializing MEDIA_ROOT before each Django Test

Tags: python, django, python-unittest

I want to my Django tests to create and modify media files. So, much like Django tests do with databases, I want to set up an empty MEDIA_ROOT folder before each test is run.

I figured I'll create a temporary folder and point MEDIA_ROOT to it. However, I can't figure out where to put the code that does this. In [this example](http://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2013/06/26/media-root-and-django-tests/), a special `Runner` is created. The runner sets up the media root and tears it down.

Unfortunately, `setup_test_environment` is called once before the first test function is run, and not every time a test is run.

I tried creating a `FileSystemTestCase` class that sets up the file system in its `setUp` function, and have all my test cases derive from it. While this works, it requires every person who writes a testcase to remember to call my `setUp` method, as it's not called automatically.

Usually I wouldn't bother with this, but the cost of forgetting to call the parent setUp method can be very high - if someone forgets the call and the tests are accidentally run on a live system, bad things will happen.

EDIT: The temporary solution I've found was to implement *both* my own runner and a base `TestCase`. Both set up a temporary MEDIA_ROOT, so if someone forgets to call my `setUp` method, the test will run in the temporary folder of the previous test, or the one set up by the runner. This can cause tests to fail, but will not ruin live data.

I'm hoping for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to me that you're trying to address two separate issues:

1. Allow tests to run independently (with regard to `MEDIA_ROOT`) when testers do the right thing (i.e. inherit from your test class and call your `setUp()`).
2. Keep testers from messing up real data when they accidentally do the wrong thing.

Given that, I think a two-pronged approach makes sense. Your `setUp()` solves problem 1. Setting up `MEDIA_ROOT` in the test runner, though, hides the fact that your testers have done the wrong thing. Instead I would just focus on protecting the data: for example, you could set `MEDIA_ROOT` to `None`. That would shield the real data in `MEDIA_ROOT`; make it more likely that the tester will see an error if they don't use your `setUp()`; and reduce code duplication.

A more robust approach would be to write your own test runner that does the setup before each test (modeled after the way Django handles the database), but that may be overkill for your needs.