# Initializing MEDIA_ROOT and the Django Storage before each test

Tags: python, django, django-tests

As explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841038/initializing-media-root-before-each-django-test), I'm trying to isolate file-system changes done in Django tests.

I'm basically changing `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` before the tests are run. Unfortunately, the Django storage class seems to be unaffected by it, so files are saved in the original location even though `MEDIA_ROOT` is pointing to another, temporary, directory.

How do I reinitialized the Django Storage system to reflect the new media root?

UPDATE: The problem is that the settings file is preloaded into a `django.conf.Settings` object, and any changes to `settings.MEDIA_ROOT` are not reflected in the preloaded instance. I still don't know how to overcome this problem.

Comment: Where do you change ``settings.MEDIA_ROOT``, in your tests, in yourapp.settings ?

Comment: In my Test class, as well as the TestRunner class.

Comment: And does each file has a different ``MEDIA_ROOT`` ?

Comment: No. Some tests create multiple files under the same MEDIA_ROOT.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out I just need to change both settings:

```
from django.conf import settings as django_settings
from project import settings

django_settings.MEDIA_ROOT = settings.MEDIA_ROOT = '....'
```

This fixes the problem.

Perhaps another problem is that I'm not using `django.conf.settings` throughout the system, but rather my own imported settings. I'll change that at some point.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use Django's [built-in feature to override settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#overriding-settings) in tests. That's exactly what it's designed for.

Straight from the docs, notice `with self.settings`:

```
from django.test import TestCase

class LoginTestCase(TestCase):

    def test_login(self):

        # First check for the default behavior
        response = self.client.get('/sekrit/')
        self.assertRedirects(response, '/accounts/login/?next=/sekrit/')

        # Then override the LOGIN_URL setting
        with self.settings(LOGIN_URL='/other/login/'):
            response = self.client.get('/sekrit/')
            self.assertRedirects(response, '/other/login/?next=/sekrit/')
```

Comment: Ooooh, that seems like a good idea! I'll add that in my setUp() method and clean up in tearDown()!

Comment: @zmbq Be careful, this is a [context manager](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) so it will not work with `setUp` and `tearDown`. The change to `settings` is only active while you're "inside the indented block".

Comment: I'm pretty sure I can call `self.settings(...)` in setUp, save the resulting context and close it in tearDown. However, it's not enough because of the problem I mentioned in my original question - I also need to change the MEDIA_ROOT from the test runner, to avoid problems when people forget to call setUp.